# Eliminate Errors

Tags: sql

Here is what I am struggling with.

This is a clocking system and I want to take out the errors.

Trying a select statment to get all the records where there is a duplicate "clock in" or duplicate "clock out" for the same user.

You have an `employee_ID` and a direction.

The data looks something like this:

```
ID.......employee_ID.........Direction

 1. .........1..................In
 2. .........2..................In
 3. .........3..................In
 4. .........1..................Out
 5. .........2..................Out
 6. .........3..................In
```

So record 6 would be an error.

Comment: And your approach is ...? And it doesn't work because ...?

Answer (score 0):

as you say its a clocking system, you need to have a timestamp or a auto increment id column, based on which you can check the last event (latest timestamp or the max id) for every emp Id before inserting (as part of trigger).

Answer (score 0):

You could also think about having one row for each shift.  This row would hold both the clock-in and clock-out timestamp.  Your datediff operations would be much less complex with this design.